# How do I tell CanCan to fetch only specific records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have posts that I am trying to load, but only want to load those where the published_at attribute is not nil.  I've tried various combinations as mentioned in the wiki docs, but keeping getting exceptions and am not sure what I'm missing.  How do I tell CanCan that any user can :read posts that have published_at != nil?

Comment: I think that this is a bit different. Cancan is used for authorization and not so much querying an index. Would you do something like `@books = Book.find(:all, :conditions => ["published_at not null"])`

Comment: Hrm, docs made it seem possible but maybe I'm reading it wrong.  I'm skipping CanCan for now, as there really isn't anything to even be authorized at this point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your Ability.rb :

```
can :edit, Post do |post|
  post.published_at.nil?
end
```

If you are really talking about CanCan authorization and not querying for posts :) In case you just want to query, a scope will do in your Post model:

```
scope :not_published, where(:published_at => nil)
```

EDIT: scope for NOT nil :

```
scope :published, where('published_at is not NULL')
```

Comment: The OP wants all posts where `published_at` is NOT null. Your `scope` fetches posts the other way round.

Comment: you are right, sorry about that, i added the other version as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a bit different. Cancan is used for authorization and not so much querying an index. Would you do something like @books = Book.find(:all, :conditions => ["published_at not null"])

Once you have this configured you can check to see if the user has the ability to update/edit/create/destroy/etc the record. If you want to list them all you would go through the normal indexing of them. If you wanted to add an edit button if the user is able to modify the records then you could put a `if can? :update, book` then show the edit button.

Comment: I guess you have a typo in `conditions`. Should it not be `:conditions => ["published_at is not null"]`. However, `Book.where('published_at is not null')` seems better. You might want to check http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface out.
Using a scope should be better in this case as suggested by @SpyrosP : something as `scope :published_posts, where('published_at is not NULL')`

Answer (score 0):

Simply think the other way around and use `cannot` method instead.

```ruby
# If it is NOT hidden, allow to read
can :read, Post, :hidden_at => nil

# If it is NOT published, disallow the read
cannot :read, Post, :published_at => nil
```

You must call the `cannot` method **AFTER** the `can` method call as explained in [Ability Precedence](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence)